# For the purpose of filing taxes in Canada, is participating in ESPP considered to exercising stock options?

Tags: taxes, canada, payroll-taxes, espp

My tax professional and company payroll department are in a disagreement about what box on the T4 the taxable benefit of my ESPP should be included in. The payroll (Canadian office of a US based company) insists that box 38 should include only "stock options exercised", and not taxable benefit from ESPP. The person helping me to file taxes, thinks that ESPP should be included in box 38 as it is also considered "stock options exercised". Who of them is "correct"?

Comment: ESPP is generally considered salary, not stock options.